# How can we get multiple cosine similarity calculations on combinations of word documents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cosine-similarity, countvectorizer

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop through resumes in a folder, then loop through job descriptions in another folder, and find the cosine similarity of each resume to each job description. Here's the code that I'm testing.

```
import os
import docx2txt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# all resumes     
ext = ('.docx')
resume_path = 'C:\\Users\\Cosine Similarity\\resumes\\'

resumes = []
# load the data
for files in os.listdir(resume_path):
    if files.endswith(ext):
        resumes.append(files)


# all job descriptions
ext = ('.docx')
job_path = 'C:\\Users\\Cosine Similarity\\job_descriptions\\'
 
jobs = []      
# load the data
for files in os.listdir(job_path):
    if files.endswith(ext):
        jobs.append(files)  

print(resumes)
print(jobs)


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import itertools


documents = resumes + jobs
#print(documents)

#indexes = [index for index in range(len(documents))]


# Vectorize the documents
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

# Get all combinations of documents
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(range(len(documents)), 2))

# Calculate cosine similarity for each pair of documents
similarities = []
for i, j in combinations:
    sim = cosine_similarity(vectors[i], vectors[j])[0][0]
    similarities.append((i, j, sim))

# Print the results
for i, j, sim in similarities:
    print(f"Similarity between document {i+1} and {j+1}: {sim:.2f}")
```

This kind of works, but not really. Here's my output.

```
Similarity between document 1 and 2: 0.14
Similarity between document 1 and 3: 0.20
Similarity between document 1 and 4: 0.34
Similarity between document 1 and 5: 0.41
Similarity between document 1 and 6: 0.25
Similarity between document 1 and 7: 0.19
Similarity between document 1 and 8: 0.52
etc., etc., etc.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to map the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 to the name of the docx file that it represents.

This is resumes: `['aaron.docx', 'dennis.docx', 'ryan.docx', 'tim.docx', 'tom.docx']`

This is jobs: `['job_description1.docx', 'job_description2.docx', 'job_description3.docx']`

Finally, I'm trying to compare 'aaron.docx' to 'job_description1.docx', 'job_description2.docx', & 'job_description3.docx'. Then dennisto 'job_description1.docx', 'job_description2.docx', & 'job_description3.docx', etc. I think the code is comparing aaron to dennis and arron to ryan. That's not right at all.

Comment: I just updated my original post. I think this is pretty close. There is no error now, but there's still something off somewhere.